# Minio/AWS-S3 upload file using multipart

Tags: amazon-s3, multipart, minio

I know that to upload binary file we should use `multipart` instead of `Form-Urlencoded`! but it seems like AWS-S3/Minio does not support it. Minio returns following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><Message>A header you provided
implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Key></Key>
<BucketName></BucketName>
<Resource>/chats/k0ydjPjA6yIBKEOdlU3HzPCmaJdQfxz83z0VyC1m</Resource>
<RequestId>3L137</RequestId><HostId>3L137</HostId></Error>
```

I use `retrofit 2` to create query like this

```
Call<Void> minio_uploadFile(@Url String url,@Part("file") RequestBody description,
 @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
 @QueryMap(encoded = true) Map<String,String>formData);
```

can anyone help me?
or I must use Form-Urlencoded to upload files?!

Comment: would it possible for you report this issue on https://github.com/minio/minio/issues. Thank you

Comment: @hossein-nasr were you able to solve the issue? if not please join us https://minio.slack.com, we would love to help you.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Does Minio support POST form upload?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, I did not follow this method anymore, I used `PUT` method instead. maybe they add support for it.

Comment: Looks like they have this ability https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/cmd/api-router.go#L69 , need to understand how to use it properly